# Is there a momentum option for Adam optimizer in Keras?

Tags: optimization, machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, keras

The question says it all. Since Adam is performing good with most of the datasets, I wanna try momentum tuning for Adam optimizer. So far I only find momentum option for SGD in Keras

Comment: Adam, by concept, has already something like momentum. Adding an outer layer momentum, i would not call it Adam anymore (and it's unclear if it's a good idea; probably not).

Comment: Bro, the "M" in ADAM literally stands for momentum.... It's already incorporated

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Short answer: **no**, neither in [Keras](https://keras.io/optimizers/#adam) nor in [Tensorflow](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/AdamOptimizer)  [EDIT: see UPDATE at the end]

Long answer: as already mentioned in the comments, Adam already incorporates something like momentum. Here is some relevant corroboration:

From the highly recommended [*An overview of gradient descent optimization algorithms*](http://ruder.io/optimizing-gradient-descent/index.html#adam) (available also as a [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1609.04747)):

> In addition to storing an exponentially decaying average of past squared gradients u[t] like Adadelta and RMSprop, Adam also keeps an exponentially decaying average of past gradients m[t], similar to momentum

From [Stanford CS231n: CNNs for Visual Recognition](http://cs231n.github.io/neural-networks-3/#ada):

> Adam is a recently proposed update that looks a bit like RMSProp with momentum

Notice that some frameworks actually include a `momentum` parameter for Adam, but this is actually the `beta1` parameter; here is [CNTK](https://cntk.ai/pythondocs/cntk.learners.html#cntk.learners.adam):

> **momentum** (float, list, output of `momentum_schedule()`) – momentum schedule. Note that this is the beta1 parameter in the Adam paper. For additional information, please refer to the [this CNTK Wiki article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cognitive-toolkit/BrainScript-SGD-Block#converting-learning-rate-and-momentum-parameters-from-other-toolkits).

That said, there is an ICLR 2016 paper titled [Incorporating Nesterov momentum into Adam](https://openreview.net/forum?id=OM0jvwB8jIp57ZJjtNEZ), along with an [implementation skeleton](https://github.com/tdozat/Optimization) in Tensorflow by the author - cannot offer any opinion on this, though.

**UPDATE**: Keras indeed includes now an optimizer called `Nadam`, based on the ICLR 2016 paper mentioned above; from the [docs](https://keras.io/optimizers/#nadam):

> Much like Adam is essentially RMSprop with momentum, Nadam is Adam RMSprop with Nesterov momentum.

It is also included in Tensorflow as a contributed module [`NadamOptimizer`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/opt/NadamOptimizer).